# Posting a ViewModel containing a list of objects with Ajax.BeginForm (MVC 4)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, wpf, asp.net-mvc-4

The view successfully passes the controller a SidebarViewModel object, but the Filters data member is null. So the binding is failing somewhere.

After some reading, I feel like the list of FilterViewModels isn't binding because the binder can't deduce that Filters[0].Value is a FilterViewModel, because none of the other data members for that view model are present. But adding the remaining data members as hidden fields didn't fix the issue.

Any idea why the list of FilterViewModels isn't binding?

**ViewModels**

```
public class SidebarViewModel
{
    public List<FilterViewModel> Filters;
}

public class FilterViewModel
{
    public string DisplayName { get; internal set; }
    public string EditorTemplate { get; internal set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model SidebarViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Filter", "Controller", Model, new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "tool-wrapper",
    LoadingElementId = "loading-image",
    HttpMethod = "POST"
}))
{
    <fieldset>
        @foreach (var filter in Model.Filters.Where(x => x.Visible).Select((value, i) => new {i, value}))
        {
            <div class="control-group">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Filters[filter.i].DisplayName)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filters[filter.i], "Template")
            </div>
        }

        <button type="submit">Filter</button>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Editor Template**

```
@model FilterViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Value, Model.Items, "(Select)")
```

**Generated HTML Form**

```
<select id="Filters_0__Value" name="Filters[0].Value">
    <option value="">(Select)</option>
    // More options
</select>

<select id="Filters_1__Value" name="Filters[1].Value">
    <option value="">(Select)</option>
    // More options
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Filter(SidebarViewModel sidebar)
{
    // Stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Filters` is a field, not a property, so you need to add getter and setter so the `DefaultModelBinder` can set the value.

```
public class SidebarViewModel
{
    public List<FilterViewModel> Filters { get; set; }
}
```

However you also have some other problems since your code will not give you correct model binding. You need to rename you `EditorTemplate` to `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/FilterViewModel.cshtml` and then in the main view use (no `foreach` loop)

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m)
```

The `EditorFor()` method will correctly generate the controls for each item with the correct name attributes (including the indexer). Note also that you should filter the collection in the controller before you pass it to the view.